# Integral manifolds of 1-distribution given by vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ that never vanishes, we define the smooth 1-distribution on $M$ by $D_p = \langle X_p \rangle $ for all $p\in M$. My intuition tells me that the image of the maximal integral curve that starts at a point $p$ is the maximal connected integral manifold of the distribution that passes trough that point $p$.

Let's see how I would go by proving this. I hope people completes the proof and/or corrects whats wrong with it.

We take the maximal integral curve $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to M$ (I'm assuming the vector field is complete) that starts at $p$ that is
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha'(t) = X_{\alpha(t)}\\
\alpha(0) = p
\end{cases}
$$

as the vector field never vanishes that implies that $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$ so we have that $\alpha$ is an inmersion (and is not constant).
If it's injective, fine we have that $(\alpha(\mathbb{R}), \iota)$ is a inmersed submanifold, because is the image of a smooth injective inmersion. And is clearly going to be an integral manifold because
$$
d\iota_h(T_h\alpha(\mathbb{R})) = D_h
$$

we can prove this last equality with some simple calculation and using the fact that we have 1-dimensional vector spaces.

If $\alpha$ is not injective I know is going to be periodic (this is an exercise in Lee's smooth manifolds) I can use the smooth covering map of the circle $\varepsilon: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ , $t \mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi i t}{T}}$ where $T$ is the smallest period of the curve. I can pass to the quotient
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}@>\alpha>>M\\
@V\varepsilon VV {_{\rlap{ \overline{\alpha}}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{2.5em}{0em}]{}}}}\\
S^1@.
\end{CD}

where $\alpha = \overline{\alpha}\circ\varepsilon$ and I will be using that $\alpha$ is constant on the fibers of $\varepsilon$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ will end up being inmersion and injective because I will use that
$$ 
\alpha(t) = \alpha(t') \iff t - t' = kT \text{ for some } k\in \mathbb{Z} 
$$

So $\overline{\alpha}(S^1) = \alpha(\mathbb{R})$ is an inmersed submanifold because is the image of an smooth injective inmersion $\overline{\alpha}$. We can prove that is an integral submanifold the same way as before.

**Here is where my problem starts.** **I want to show the maximality of $\alpha(\mathbb{R})$** (is clearly connected as is the image of a connected space over a continuous function).

Let's take another integral connected submanifold $(N, \iota)$ that passes trough $p$, that is
$$
p \in N\\
d\iota_h(T_hN) = D_h \ \forall h\in N
$$
I want to show that $N \subset \alpha(\mathbb{R})$. I take $q \in N$ we should be able to conclude that $q \in \alpha(\mathbb{R})$ **my intuition tells me we should use the maximality of the integral curves of the vector field.** This is the best I got:

As $N$ is connected and locally path-connected then is path-connected, let's take $\sigma: [0, 1] \to N$ smooth curve such that
$$
\sigma(0) = \iota^{-1}(p), \
\sigma(1) = \iota^{-1}(q)
$$
where $\iota: N \to M$ is the injective inmersion. We define $\beta = \iota \circ \alpha : [0, 1] \to M $. Now see that
$$
\beta'(t) = (d\iota)_{\alpha(t)} \circ \alpha'(t) \\
\beta'(t) \in (d\iota)_{\alpha(t)}(T_{\alpha(t)}N) = D_{\iota\circ\alpha(t)} = D_{\beta(t)}
$$
Where I'm using that $N$ is integral submanifold. Now I'm stuck because this seems not to imply that $\beta$ is an integral curve of the vector field, but at best
$$
\begin{cases}
\beta'(t) = A(t)X_{\beta(t)} \ \text{  for some continuous function $A(t)$}\\
\beta(0) = p
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in the definition of $\beta$. I think you mean $\beta=\iota \circ \sigma$.

Having said that, you almost got it.
Since
$$
\begin{cases}
\beta'(t) = A(t)X_{\beta(t)} \ \text{  for some continuous function $A(t)$}\\
\beta(0) = p
\end{cases}
$$
you can obtain a reparametrization $\tilde{\beta}=\beta \circ \varphi$, with $\varphi: I\subset \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\tilde{\beta}'(t) = X_{\tilde{\beta}(t)} \\
\tilde{\beta}(0) = p
\end{cases}
$$

But how would we find such a function $\varphi$?

We want

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\beta \circ \varphi(t)) = X_{\tilde{\beta}(t)}.$$
Then
$$\beta'(\varphi(t)) \cdot \varphi'(t) = X_{\beta(\varphi(t))} = X_{\tilde{\beta}(t)}.$$

But we had $\beta'(\varphi(t)) = A(\varphi(t))X_{\beta(\varphi(t))}$. And we need $A(\varphi(t)) \cdot \varphi'(t) = 1$. So, we need to find $\varphi(t)$ such that this equation holds:
$$
\varphi'(t) = \frac{1}{A(t)}
$$.

Then we can solve for $\varphi$ by integrating both sides with respect to $t$:

$\varphi(t) = \int \frac{1}{A(t)} dt + C$,

where $C$ is the constant of integration.

The function $\varphi(t)$ thus obtained will not necessarily be surjective onto the interval $[0,1]$, though. In order to ensure this, we would have to adjust the constant of integration $C$ and potentially also scale the function $\varphi$ appropriately. For example, suppose $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi(8)=0.5$. We can take
$$
\tilde{\varphi}(t)=2\varphi(t/2), \text{ with } t\in[0,16]
$$
There are some restrictions to the form of the function $A(t)$, for example, $A(t)\neq 0$. But I think that this can be required by an appropriate choice of $\sigma$.

I hope that this answer, although incomplete, help you to finish your work.